# How can I link my production application to my production database in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.

I use **.env** that locate in my root directory to set the configuration in order to link my application to my local database.

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=REtW71G*****VgHqmzXsuvqL8ziFR

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
```

Now, I want to hook up my production application to my production database instead.

I've tried editing the **.env.example**
But it doesn't seem to take any effect.

Do I need to use something like this ? If so, where should I use this ? Which file of Laravel 5 ? I'm not sure.

```
if ($app->environment('local'))
{
    // The environment is local
}

if ($app->environment('local', 'staging'))
{
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
}
```

What is the most efficient way link your production application to your production database ?

Comment: rename .env.example to .env on your production application

Comment: Let me try that. What should I put in my APP_KEY ? Leave it as `default` or put same as my `local` ?

Comment: I have 2 environments, but I only have one `config\app.php` . Do I need to create a new file for my production environment ?

Comment: it depends, if they are similiar .env file is enough. On the APP_KEY and quoting the Laravel documentation "Typically, this string should be 32 characters long. The key can be set in the .env environment file. If the application key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not be secure!"

Comment: How do I set it ? Should I just inputing some random number ? Does it have to be match anywhere elses ?

Comment: No, you have a command for that, `php artisan key:generate` it will set the key on your .env file ;)

Comment: btw here's the documentation for laravel configuration http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#configuration

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion work. 100%.  You should answer it cuz you earned it.

Comment: Alright, it might help other developers

Comment: Please don’t add the **laravel-4** tag if this is a Laravel 5-specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fabio Antunes

**First**

in your production server, re-name your `.env.example` --> `.env`

---

**Second**

you should have something similar to this in your .env file on your production server

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=****// you need to create this key // ****
DB_HOST= http://48.23.91.132/
DB_DATABASE=database-name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=iU308475987MTJ9JdMvN
```

---

**Third**

Create your APP_KEY `php artisan key:generate`

---

**Forth**

Testing if it's work.

- Write a simple migration script
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- In your command-line, you should see something like this :

[image]

Another test would be

Configure you database with an application like :

**MySQL Workbench** or **Sequel Pro**

- Migration Table should be added.
- Table should be added

[image]

---

**DONE**

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you were editing `.env.example` and as the name suggests this is just and example file. You have to rename it or create a copy and name it `.env`.

In that file set your production configs and if you want an APP_KEY you have to add that field and it **can't be blank** in this case I set it as yada

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=yada

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
```

Now since our key is not that good we generate a new one with an artisan  command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using homestead, add the "port" to DB_HOST.

Ex.:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

If you want to link to production database. Change your DB_HOST..etc. But, check first if your production database/server accepts external connections.